# Bash script - perform grep on filenames containing particular numbers

Tags: bash, grep, command-substitution, brace-expansion

I have a bunch of files such as:

```
jobReports/NARX_20191212_1.out
jobReports/NARX_20191212_10.out
jobReports/NARX_20197695_2.out
jobReports/NARX_20197695_3.out
jobReports/NARX_20261798_1.out
```

where the first numeral sequence denotes a jobID, and the second numeral sequence denotes the arrayID.

I want to perform a search on all the `.out` files in that directory with jobID equal to `20197695` or `20261798`.

In the command line, this works:

```
grep "Saving results to" jobReports/NARX_{20197695,20261798}*.out | wc -l
```

, which gives me a count of occurences of that string in the desired files. In my script I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
myJobs = ( 20197695, 20261798 )
IFS=, eval 'myJobs_string="${myJobs[*]}"'
echo $(grep "Saving results to" jobReports/NARX_{$myJobs_string}*.out |wc -l)
```

when running, I get the error:

```
grep: jobReports/NARX_{: No such file or directory
grep: 20197695: No such file or directory
grep: }*.out: No such file or directory
```

So looks like inside the script, the brace expansion is not working as I expected...what can I do to fix this?

Comment: why eval? why not `jobReports/NARX_{${myJobs[@]}}*.out `

Comment: why myJobs is an array and not a simple variable "{20197695, 20261798}"

Comment: You cannot use a variable inside braces for brace expansion. When you do, the `','` loses all significance and is simply part of a string. Just loop over your array and keep a `sum` of the lines resulting your `grep ... | wc -l` for each array member.

Comment: @kyodev Good point, I did not think of that. But it (the solution you posted) still gives me the same problem

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So is there no way to do brace expansion with an array for grep as I wanted to?

Comment: double quote around variable: `jobReports/NARX_{"$myJobs_string"}*.out`

Comment: `"$myJobs_string"` is only `"${myJobs_string[@]}"` and with your `myJobs_string="${myJobs[*]}`, myJobs_string is not an arrey

Comment: Not using an array at all would seem like the obvious, trivial workaround in this particular case. `grep "Saving results to" jobReports/NARX_20197695*.out jobReports/NARX_20261798*.out`

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

myJobs=( 20197695, 20261798 )
ifs_ini="$IFS"
IFS+=','
myJobs_string=( ${myJobs[*]} )
IFS="$ifs_ini"

echo myJobs ${myJobs[@]}
echo myJobs_string ${myJobs_string[@]}
echo jobReports/NARX_{${myJobs_string[@]}}*.out
grep -c 'Saving results to.*$' jobReports/NARX_{"$myJobs_string"}*.out
bash --version
```

output

```
myJobs 20197695 20261798
myJobs_string 20197695 20261798
jobReports/NARX_{20197695 20261798}*.out
<not tested>
```

PS: `grep -c ...` is the same as `echo $( echo grep ... | wc -l )`

Comment: I tried the following in my script:

    `myJobs=( 20367893 ); ifi_ini="$IFS"; IFS+=','; myJobs_string=( ${myJobs[*]} ); IFS="$ifs_ini"; echo 'Total ' $(grep "Saving results to" 
    jobReports/NARX_{"$myJobs_string"}*.out | wc -l) ' completed jobs';`

The error I get is: 

`grep: jobReports/NARX_{20367893}*.out: No such file or directory`

As a check: 

`grep "Saving results to" jobReports/NARX_{20367893}*.out |wc -l`

gives me a correct count.

Comment: please, use for test my code. In yours, it is not a array for final display. Use indentation, no code here. Check with https://www.shellcheck.net/. @Asy